# How to get a property in a dynamically created Object in a dynamically created Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, dynamic

Basically, I have this dynamically created object being sent back from a PHP script that I put into an array. I store where it's located in the array in the tools the user uses to select what to view as well as what the property in the object I want to get.

Example:

```
Object{
  Property1: string
  Property2: Int
  Property3: Object{
                 innerObjProperty1: Array
                 innerObjProperty2: string
             }
  Property4: Object{
                 innerObjProperty1: Array
                 innerObjProperty2: string
             }
  Property5: Object{
                 innerObjProperty1: Array
                 innerObjProperty2: string
             }
}
```

And that would be one object inside an array

```
array={object1, object2}
```

And that array is populated dynamically based on user input.

Now, if I wanted to grab the innerObjProperty1 in an array from object1 I know I could easily do

```
array[object1].Property3.innerObjProperty1
```

But, the problem there is that, since it's user based, I what point in the array and which property is being selected is up to the user. The value inside the inner object will always be the same selected (innerObjProperty1 as it's the array of values they want to see), but what property of the object is dependent upon a select box.

I have the selects set up where there's an id tied to them that has array location and property name, but I know of no short hand way to quick select the object based on a variable. For example:

```
var theSplit= $(this).attr("id").split("|");
var arrayItem = theSplit[0];
var objProperty = theSplit[1];
alert(array[arrayItem].objProperty.innerObjProperty1;
```

would never work. Is there any short hand method? Or should do I have to use a function to loop through each item of the property to find the one that equals the objProperty? Sorry if it seems simple, but I feel like I'd rather use any short hand to get to it if possible and I can't think of one. Looping through the object in the array isn't too hard, just want to see if there's a simpler method either with JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: Could you please differentiate more accurately between arrays (`[]` literal syntax, numeric indices) and objects (`{}` literal syntax, string keys)?

Comment: I think `array[arrayItem][objProperty].innerObjProperty1` would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hah, wow.. I feel dumb. For some reason I wasn't thinking of that working the same as with a multidimensional array. But yes, that definitely works. Sometimes the simplest things escape me >.>

Thank you very much :)